# What is the best heart beat range for a 5k training?

Tags: fat, heart-rate, 5k

I started to running as a 3 days a week train a month ago, I did a 5k run to know, and my time was 32.30, I want to get it down to 27 by the next race in 2 months. I'm doing 2 heart range trains and 1 pace every week.

I’m not sure what’s the best heart range for me, I'm 20 years old, 90kg about 200pounds, 173cm, when I run my heart go to 180 in an easy pace, and in a sprint it gets to 210. In a calm walk after a run it goes really fast to 140, in 40 seconds or so.

So, is it a good training to sprint every time i can get back to 140? So I stay always in a tough situation. Or should I stay in the 180 with a slow pace?

Ill ad any information as needed, thanks for the help.

Comment: Your heart rate will vary wildly from day to day, even with the same amount of exercise. Also, as you get used to training, the same effort will produce a lower heart rate. I would find a good 5k running programme and forget about measuring your heart rate, other than as a means to gauge recovery (How fast it drops after exercise).

Answer (score 1):

You are really asking two questions. Your first question is "what kind of training plan should I be using to improve my 5K running times?" There are a lot of different plans online; they will prescribe heart rate ranges, typically based on your age. Those aren't particularly accurate, but they are a decent place to start.

It is also possible to set training ranges using a field test - where you go out, run a prescribed stress test, and measure your heart rate - but it's not something that I would recommend for somebody who has just started running.

I recommend finding a good running-specific forum, and asking them your question.

Comment: :) You say he's asking two questions. What's the second one?